# Error trying to access an URL from my NEXTJS site

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-routing

I have the following problem. I have a website that I've created using NextJS and I've created some different dynamic pages into it. The problem occurs when I try to access the URL of those dynamic pages from any place that's not my navbar, or when I reload one of these dynamic pages: it gives me a 404 screen and I don't know exactly what causes this inconvenient.

**Next Config.js file**

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow! - Rather than describing an issue, please provide surrounding code of all files that are involved - Here is a handy guide  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, i've just updated the question with my next config.js code, the rest of the code has a lot of content and doesn't make sense to write it down here

Comment: You should really try to extrapolate the code that you think causes the problem or it is directly related to the problem in order for us to be able to spot an issue. Otherwise, it's just anyone's guess.